# Reinstall NodeJS and npm

Tags: nodejs, npm, reinstall

I installed NodeJS and npm in 14.04 in the hope of setting up Ionic Framework. But there seems to be something wrong and I was told to reinstall NodeJS and npm. Can someone please give me the commands to do the same ?

Comment: How did you install them in the first place?

Comment: I followed some guide available on net. I closed that tab and don't know how I can recover it. I used command line to do the same.

Comment: Then it will be very difficult to provide assistance because we do not know how it was installed in the first place.

Comment: @ThomasW. , found it             sudo apt-get install curl
curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs

Answer (score 2):

You can simply download nodejs binaries for linux from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ (preferably LTS version 4.4.3). Unzip it and place it anywhere you want (say /opt folder). Now you can link to bin/node and bin/npm commands in your ~/.bashrc file using alias

alias node='/opt/node-v4.4.3/bin/node'

alias npm='/opt/node-v4.4.3/bin/npm'

Its simplest and you know exactly your files are.

Note : Please do not use `ln -s` into `/usr/bin` as it won't work