# I have installed cordova succesfully but is showing cordova: command not found

Tags: software-installation, nodejs

```
harish@harish-Lenovo-G510:~$ sudo npm install -g cordova
[sudo] password for harish: 
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
harish@harish-Lenovo-G510:~$ nodejs --version
v0.10.25
harish@harish-Lenovo-G510:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
harish@harish-Lenovo-G510:~$ npm --version
4.4.1
harish@harish-Lenovo-G510:~$ git --version
git version 2.1.4
harish@harish-Lenovo-G510:~$ sudo npm install -g cordova
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v0.10.25
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as 
we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this 
version.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
/home/harish/.npm-packages/bin/cordova -> /home/harish/.npm-
packages/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/home/harish/.npm-packages/lib
`-- cordova@7.0.0 
  `-- cordova-lib@7.0.0
    `-- cordova-js@4.2.1
      `-- browserify@13.3.0
        `-- stream-http@2.7.1 

harish@harish-Lenovo-G510:~$ cordova --version
cordova: command not found
harish@harish-Lenovo-G510:~$ node -v
v0.10.25
```

Comment: `npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v0.10.25
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as 
we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this 
version.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead` - Why dont you do as suggested?

Comment: you'd need to install latest nodejs https://askubuntu.com/questions/750531/reinstall-nodejs-and-npm/764384#764384

Answer (score 1):

you need to install the latest version of `nodejs`:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs=6.*
```

and then try to install `cordova`