# Trouble with NodeJS and the npx command on 22.04 LTS

Tags: bash, nodejs

I am trying to create my first react app via the npx command.
I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750531/reinstall-nodejs-and-npm) answer to a question similar to mine.
So I tried this:

> alias node='/home/sks/Downloads/node18.18.2/bin/node'

> alias npm='/home/sks/Downloads/node18.18.2/bin/npm'

> alias npx='/home/sks/Downloads/node18.18.2/bin/npx'

as a bash_aliases file

When I run $npx create-react-app app-name, the terminal does nothing. No errors, no folder creation, no nothing.
I then do run the command with an --info flag

> sks@sks:~$ npx create-react-app myapp 
> ^C (**At this point I hit cancel, because no matter how long I wait nothing happens**)
> sks@sks:~$ npx create-react-app myapp --info

> Environment Info:

> > current version of create-react-app: 5.0.1
> > running from /home/sks/node_modules/create-react-app

> System:
> >>OS: Linux 6.2 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
> >>CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz
> Binaries:
> >>Node: 18.18.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node
> >>Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
> >>npm: 9.8.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/npm
> Browsers:
> >>Chrome: 118.0.5993.70
> npmPackages:
>
> > react: Not Found
> > react-dom: Not Found
> > react-scripts: Not Found
> > npmGlobalPackages:
> > >>create-react-app: Not Found

> sks@sks:~$ npm install create-react-app
> (⠂⠂
> ⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠧ (**---> This part's not moving and I see no progress no matter how long I wait**) idealTree:sks: sill idealTree buildDeps

I also have yarn installed on my Ubuntu.
Finally what the terminal seems like after I created the aliases file.

Can somenone tell me how am I going to run/install ReactJS on my Linux. Note that I also found a thread on [github where the user faced the same problem as mine](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13339) and the solution he came up with was to create another user and install NodeJS in there so for the whole proccess to take place!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block]s to format.